# Problems with installing pandoc

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, installation, pandoc

I'm trying to install pandoc on a new Ubuntu machine. First, I installed the haskell platform. Then I installed pandoc with the command `cabal install pandoc`, but then got the following error message. How can I fix it?

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Data.Ipynb       ( src/Data/Ipynb.hs, dist/build/Data/Ipynb.o )

src/Data/Ipynb.hs:152:23: error:
    • No instance for (Ord Value)
        arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
      Possible fix:
        use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
          so you can specify the instance context yourself
    • When deriving the instance for (Ord JSONMeta)
    |
152 |   deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Generic, Semigroup, Monoid, FromJSON)
    |                       ^^^

src/Data/Ipynb.hs:479:23: error:
    • No instance for (Ord Value)
        arising from the first field of ‘JsonData’ (type ‘Value’)
      Possible fix:
        use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
          so you can specify the instance context yourself
    • When deriving the instance for (Ord MimeData)
    |
479 |   deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Generic)
    |                       ^^^
Failed to install ipynb-0.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ipynb-0.2-12lvW0D0287FL7WAB5JQxT failed during the building phase. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
pandoc-2.17.0.1-5yDcj1RH0pT4FRdq4hDaRb depends on pandoc-2.17.0.1 which failed
to install.
```

Comment: no need to build from source, see https://pandoc.org/installing.html

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be using an ancient version of the `aeson` package. Up to verion 1.5.1.0, [its `Value` type did not have an `Ord` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Value). But the `ipynb` library needs that instance, so it should have the constraint `aeson >=1.5.2` in its `.cabal` file – but it doesn't. (You may want to file a pull request about this.)

For now, you can manually use

```
cabal install pandoc --constraint 'aeson>=1.5.2'
```

(This may incur having to re-install lots of packages, or other problems!)

Comment: Correction: The bound should be `aeson >= 1.5.2.0`. Also see my PR: https://github.com/jgm/ipynb/pull/3.

Answer (score 1):

There's the easy way, if you don't need the newest version:

```
sudo apt install pandoc
```

Comment: note that this version is not up to date, see https://pandoc.org/installing.html

Comment: The version available for 20.04 LTS has almost none of the functionality of newer pandoc.